# How to clone a bootable SD card to a little smaller card?

Tags: linux, dd, disk-image

I have an 8G bootable SD card used for Raspberry Pi. Currently I bought an exactly same card, in order to clone the card. I have tried the following steps:

1. Create an image from the old card:

   > sudo dd if=/dev/rdisk3 of=SD.img bs=1m

It succeeded and the output shows:

````
7681+0 records in
7681+0 records out
8054112256 bytes transferred in 386.217068 secs (20853849 bytes/sec)```
````

2. Write the image into the new card:

   > sudo dd if=SD.img of=/dev/rdisk3 bs=1m

Here It failed and the output shows:

````
dd: /dev/rdisk3: Input/output error
7581+0 records in
7580+0 records out
7948206080 bytes transferred in 568.141243 secs (13989842 bytes/sec)```
````

I think the problem may be the difference between the number of blocks. Does it imply that these two cards don't have exactly the same size? (The new one looks smaller.) I would have to clone the card many times, so I wonder how can I make the image smaller (There's available space in it) so that I can write them to other cards, even with a little smaller size?

Comment: One seems to be 100mb smaller. Use gparted to make the larger one 110mb smaller.  Then gparted can copy the contents of one to the other.

Comment: Can you post the output of `fdisk -l /dev/rdisk3` of the original card ? If the SD Card has ~10 MB of free space at the end of the card - i.e. the `/` partition ends before the end of the SD Card, then it shouldn't matter if the SD card is 10 meg smaller as nothing would get written at the end.

Comment: That "m" needs to be upper case I believe, i.e. "...bs=1M"

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a `dd` clone? That won't be easy (maybe not possible as-is) with a smaller target drive.

How about formattng the new card & just copying the files onto it? Might result in less writes (and be faster) if the original isn't full. `dd` will copy unused space happily.

`parted` should be capable of running in a script, and can set bootable partitions & format, etc. Could see `man parted` or take a look at what commands `gparted` runs to do what you want... then automate a partition, format, copy script?

Or, if you used `gparted` or similar to shrink your current original card's partitions to a smaller size, then a `dd` image might fit on slightly smaller cards? May have to tell `dd` to stop reading after the last used partition, or it might keep reading to the "end." And it could leave some unused space on the new card. - I haven't had good luck with `dd`'ing images (especially live iso's) onto flash devices though.

Comment: This might be a good idea - the raspi dosen't need anything other than a standard FAT32 FS IIRC

Comment: It doesn't have to be a `dd` clone. But it's a bootable card with hidden partitions. How can I just copy the files and keep it bootable?